# Generic expression for EF Core 3.1 filtering throws exception on .Any(...)

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I try to create a generic way of getting data via EF Core 3.1 with the same filtering of different children. For this, I try to extract the searched expression inside of Any(...).

```
public Expression<Func<PraeparatUpdateEntity, bool>> IsToApprovePackungUpdates_Working()
{
   return entity => entity.PackungUpdates.Any(e => !e.IsImported
      && e.UpdateState != EntityUpdateState.Accepted
      && e.UpdateType != EntityUpdateType.Unchanged);
}

public Expression<Func<PraeparatUpdateEntity, bool>> IsToApprovePackungUpdates_NotWorking()
{
   var func = new Func<PackungUpdateEntity, bool>(e => !e.IsImported
      && e.UpdateState != EntityUpdateState.Accepted
      && e.UpdateType != EntityUpdateType.Unchanged);

   return entity => entity.PackungUpdates.Any(func);
}

public new async Task<ICollection<PraeparatUpdateEntity>> GetToApproveAsync(bool trackChanges = false)
{ 
   var query = Set.Include(praeparatUpdateEntity => praeparatUpdateEntity.PackungUpdates)
      .Where(IsToApprovePackungUpdates_NotWorking());
            
   if (!trackChanges)
   {
      query = query.AsNoTracking();
   }

   return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

The first version is working.
The second one fails with errormessage:

```
System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Func`2[MyProject.Data.Common.Entities.Update.PackungUpdateEntity,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[MyProject.Data.Common.Entities.Update.PackungUpdateEntity,System.Boolean]]' of method 'Boolean Any[PackungUpdateEntity](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyProject.Data.Common.Entities.Update.PackungUpdateEntity], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[MyProject.Data.Common.Entities.Update.PackungUpdateEntity,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg1')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EnumerableToQueryableMethodConvertingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyProject.Data.Repositories.PraeparatUpdateRepository.GetToApproveAsync(Boolean trackChanges) in C:\git\MyProject\Source\MyProject.Data\Repositories\PraeparatUpdateRepository.cs:line 156
   at MyProject.Data.Tests.Integration.RepositoryNavigationPropertyLoadingTests.GetAllPraeparatUpdates_WhereToApprove_WithNavigationProperties_OK_Test() in C:\git\MyProject\Source\MyProject.Data.Tests.Integration\RepositoryNavigationPropertyLoadingTests.cs:line 328
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

### ******** UPDATE ********

If I add AsQueryable() to my IEnumerable database children I can add my Expressions like that:

```
var query = Set.Include(praeparatUpdateEntity => praeparatUpdateEntity.PackungUpdates)
   .Include(praeparatUpdateEntity => praeparatUpdateEntity.SequenzUpdates)
   .ThenInclude(sequenzUpdateEntity => sequenzUpdateEntity.ApplikationsartUpdates)
   .Include(praeparatUpdateEntity => praeparatUpdateEntity.SequenzUpdates)
   .ThenInclude(sequenzUpdateEntity => sequenzUpdateEntity.DeklarationUpdates)
   .Where(IsToApprove<PraeparatUpdateEntity>()
      .OrElse(entity => entity.PackungUpdates.AsQueryable().Any(IsToApprove<PackungUpdateEntity>()))
      .OrElse(entity => entity.SequenzUpdates.AsQueryable().Any(IsToApprove<SequenzUpdateEntity>()))
      .OrElse(entity => entity.SequenzUpdates.SelectMany(sequenzUpdateEntity => sequenzUpdateEntity.ApplikationsartUpdates).AsQueryable()
         .Any(IsToApprove<ApplikationsartUpdateEntity>()))
      .OrElse(entity => entity.SequenzUpdates.SelectMany(sequenzUpdateEntity => sequenzUpdateEntity.DeklarationUpdates).AsQueryable()
         .Any(IsToApprove<DeklarationUpdateEntity>())));
```

and my generic Expression:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> IsToApprove<T>() where T : class, IUpdateEntity
{
   return entity => !entity.IsImported && entity.UpdateState != EntityUpdateState.Accepted
   && entity.UpdateType != EntityUpdateType.Unchanged;
}
```

which seems at the moment to work... Tests in progress

Comment: `If I add AsQueryable() to my IEnumerable database children` they are already `IQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`. A `DbSet<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>` which is why you can use LINQ with it. The problem is that your "generic expression" is actually a specific function call using `Any` that can't be translated to SQL. What actually works *is* an expression on a specific entity. What are you trying to do? Whatever it is it *doesn't* require such complex expressions

Comment: Are you trying to filter the child entities? You can't do that in EF Core 3.1, it's coming in EF Core 5. Filtering the child entities is *not* the same as applying all filters in the query, *after* the JOINs produced lots of empty or duplicate rows. You'd need to filter in the JOIN clauses themselves which is impossible with EF Core 3.1. In SQL you'd need `parent LEFT JOIN (select ... from child where child.IsApproved =10 c on c.ParentID=parent.ID`

Comment: Given that all those conditions are hard-coded you could create SQL Server views or functions that return only the matching objects and map your entities to them

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of PraeparateUpdateEntities (with all children) where eighter the entity himself or any child of it needs to be approved. So i don't need to filter any child entities.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework is build on top of `IQueryable` which is using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/). Those are required to analyze your code at runtime and transform it to SQL. In first snippet compiler takes all the heavy lifting of building expression trees for you. You can try building expression tree yourself, but usually it is not that simple task. In this case you can try something like this:

```
Expression<Func<PackungUpdateEntity, bool>> exp = e => !e.IsImported
      && e.UpdateState != EntityUpdateState.Accepted
      && e.UpdateType != EntityUpdateType.Unchanged;

var any = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(mi => mi.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Any) && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .Single()
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(PackungUpdateEntity));
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PraeparatUpdateEntity));
var toAny = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, nameof(PraeparatUpdateEntity.PackungUpdates));
var call = Expression.Call(any, toAny, exp); 
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<PraeparatUpdateEntity, bool>>(call, param);

return result;
```

Comment: That leads to a compiler error:
CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyProject.Data.Common.Entities.Update.PackungUpdateEntity, bool>>' to 'System.Func<MyProject.Data.Common.Entities.Update.PackungUpdateEntity, bool>'

Comment: You also need to store the return-variable to an expression.

Comment: @Angelika `entity.PackungUpdates` should be `IQueryable<PackungUpdateEntity>`

Comment: it looks as it would work if i add AsQueryable() like that `public Expression<Func<PraeparatUpdateEntity, bool>> IsToApprovePackungUpdates_MayBeWorking()
{
   Expression<Func<PackungUpdateEntity, bool>> func = e => !e.IsImported
   && e.UpdateState == EntityUpdateState.Accepted
   && e.UpdateType != EntityUpdateType.Unchanged;
   
   return entity => entity.PackungUpdates.AsQueryable().Any(func);
}`
But I'm not shure how "EVIL" that is... I don't want to change the PackungsUpdates from ICollection to IQueryable as I don't want to expose IQueryable to higher layers...

Comment: @Maarten I didn't undestand what you meant with your comment. If I store `entity => entity.PackungUpdates.Any(func)` to an Expression variable, that doesn't change my compiler error for the Any(func)- part...

Comment: @Angelika my first suggestion was not correct, please see the post. Also why you can't use the first method?

Comment: @GuruStron I need to do this check not only for PackungUpdates. I need to check 5 times. With my 1. version I can not reuse the functionality. I will shortly post an update, so you can see my current state.

Comment: @Angelika if what you actually want is to filter the child entities, you won't be able to do it in EF Core 3.1 The `.Where()` applies to the output of the `LEFT JOIN` clauses generated to pull the related objects. This means there are already a lot of duplicate or null rows. EF Core will try to reconstitute child objects based on their IDs but *won't* reapply the filter expressions after loading them. To really filter the child entities you'd need to filter in the LEFT JOIN clause, ie `LEFT JOIN (select .... where ....) child1`

Comment: @Angelika if you want related entity filtering you'll have to use EF Core 5 (still in preview, probably going into RC next month)